# Validate DateTime format of C# .NET using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

I have a datetime format customizer in my front-end and I want to validate the format the user inputted. The parsing will be done in the backend so I need to validate the format in javascript before passing it to the backend. I am using dayjs in the front-end but the formatting is far from different.

How can I do this in javascript? I don't want to call an endpoint just to validate the inputted date format since the format was validated on user input change.

Resources:
https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: >"I don't want to call an endpoint just to validate the inputted date format since the format was validated on user input change." In general, you should validate user input on both backend and frontend... not just frontend. Trusting user input, because it was validated on client side is huge security no-go.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek yep. I'm planning to validate that after whole front-end validation is okay. I just want to let the user know that the format they inputted was incorrect and the backend validation should run on final saving.